# CLLocationManager working out elevation gain

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to work out the elevation gain from CLLocationManager.

Here is my code at the moment:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *oldLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:[locations count] - 1];
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];

    double elevationChange = oldLocation.altitude - location.altitude;

    if (elevationChange > 0)
    {
        _netElevationGain += elevationChange;
    }
```

I think this code should work fine but when I test it netElevationGain is always 0. I've done some research and it seems as though it may be that I'm testing with the iOS simulator. I am using the location option in the debug menu for the iOS simulator.

Is it likely the simulator causing this problem or is there something I have missed in my code?

Comment: Add more information. So you setup 2 locations with GPX files, and you are going from one to the other and expect to see altitude changes?

Comment: @rob hi, yeah thats right but the value is always 0

Comment: Yes, CLLocation's altitude will be always equal to zero on simulator.

Answer (score 1):

So here's one potential problem: are you reverse geocoding these locations by any chance? Because if you do, I found out painfully, you will lose the altitude. It makes sense if you think about it, but a better design probably would have been for them to model the reverse geocoded location as inheriting all the properties for the GPS-derived location. It does not. So what I ended up doing was an outer class that got the LM location, extracted the altitude, and then injected it into the final 'Address' class.

Comment: I'm not sure if I am reverse geocoding or not, I don't think so (sorry I'm still pretty new to Objective-c)